# What's the word for "overly proud of your education"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, pejorative-language

A friend and I are trying to remember a word to describe someone who is overly proud of their education. An example usage would be:

> Does that email make me appear too ***_*__**?

Where the ***_*__** is the word I am looking for, in case that is not obvious. He thought the word was "erudite" but when that appears to just mean educated, it doesn't convey the sense of condescending pride we are looking for.

What is the word I we are looking for?

Comment: It also cannot be *erudite*, since that is an adjective. The construction above implies you absolutely need a noun! But I'll try to suggest some adjectives (those are easier to come by)! :)

Comment: @Josh It appears I misspoke when talking to you - I should have said "does this email make me appear too erudite?" I was falling into the bad habit of nouning an adjective.

Comment: @tryaria ah ha, you did create an account here after all! Ok, I edited my question to reflect what you said and also indicate that it was actually your question which I stole from you :-)

Comment: Hmm. After reading some comments and answers to this question I'm struck at how silly and self-referential this question is. Don't use an obscure, erudite word in place of *blank*… ;-)

Comment: I am not sure the construction implies that a noun is absolutely needed. The verb _appear_ can be followed by a noun or an adjective: _this dress make me appear fat_; _this letter makes me appear English_. _too_ is an adverb that is used as submodifier: _he wore suits that seemed a size too small for him_; _she drives too fast_. I doubt _too_ is ever followed by a noun; if that happens, it's not the most common case. (I can think of _too English_, for example.)

Comment: @kiamaluno: in the original version of the question it was worded “Does that email make me appear too much like a *blank*?”  That’s what Jimi’s comment was referring to — the current form can indeed acommodate adjectives just fine.

Comment: @tryaria you should invoke a rep recalc on this account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, I would probably use the word *smartass* or a more milder *smartypants*.

I think *condescending*, a word you used later in your question, conveys perfectly well what you're trying to ask.

> Does that email make me sound too condescending?

Comment: Yes, but I could swear that there's a better word for that. Erudite with a strongly negative cast...

Comment: @tryaria Well, there's a problem with trying to find a more obscure word than *condescending*, which conveys nicely the concern that you may have a patronizing tone and are trying to sound overly educated… can you guess what that problem might be? ;-)

Comment: Fair enough. Really though, it's just bothering me that I could swear there was a word for that. I wasn't really thinking about adding it to my normal speech, for obvious reasons.

Comment: see Mike Brown's comment on his own answer ;-)

Answer (score 15):

I was going to say "pretentious".

Perhaps **pompous** would be a good fit here.

Comment: Both are good.  I'd give the edge to pompous.

Answer (score 9):

I sometimes say, "pardon me if this sounds a bit *professorial*..."

'Hifalutin' is the closest I can think of...pretentious?

Comment: I like pretentious. It has the self-importance aspect and condescension built in.

Comment: Upvote for "pretentious", although not always correlated with education.

Answer (score 7):

Well I would personally use the word *elitist* for that role, assuming the "overly proud" emphasis is on showing up that the author has superior education.

> Does that email make me sound too *elitist*?

Failing that I would use *condescending* as @ghoppe suggested.

Comment: I like elitist too, but I think condescending is the closest. Wish I could accept both answers...

Comment: @tryaria: Quite alright, condescending is probably the correct choice.

Answer (score 3):

Some use pedantic with a negative flair, but that's not a noun. Were you to change your statement to say "Does that email make me appear too pedantic?" I think that will give you what you want.

Comment: Or one could use "smug" :-).

Comment: Apparently pedant is the acceptable noun form for pedantic.

Comment: One could argue that a bunch of people discussing rules of English might seem pedantic ;)

Comment: @Mike-Brown Pedantic is more of a "hair splitting" aspect. I mean too elitist about being well educated/well spoken.

Comment: This could fit, but to me a pedant is someone overly concerned with trivial errors at the expense of the big picture. When you're pedantic you're pointing out flaws that are largely irrelevant to the communication. I'm not sure that's the meaning he's trying to get across. But that's just me, perhaps there's more layers of meaning to the word and I'm being too… pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

Would *uppity* be the word you're looking for by chance?

There's also *snobbish*.

Comment: At least in parts of the US, *uppity* has to be used with some care: it’s got a strong history of racist usage.

Comment: @PLL ~ I was _not_ aware of that, and I'm from the Deep South. Can you expound or provide a link?

Comment: @PLL: I've also never heard of any racist connotation for "uppity". It's not a nice thing to call someone, but it doesn't imply anything about racism.

Comment: @drachenstern, @Martha: I grew up in the UK and didn’t know of any racist connotations until two US friends (one Texan, one Pennsylvanian) told me about this.  Googling for `"uppity racist"` and similar things shows that this is a hotly debated question.  Certainly some writers find it racist, eg [here, at Daily Kos](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2007/2/11/223840/971); others reckon this is an over-interpretation, eg [several posters here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080908220519AArXWvf).  But certainly “uppity negro” and “uppity n****r” have both been stock phrases [cont’d]

Comment: for a long time (again, googling provides many many instances); at least two of the OED citations for uppity are race-related; and in the [Corpus of Historical American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/), the top three noun correlates for *uppity* are *women*, *n****r*, and *blacks* (so it’s been used for sexism as well as racism).  So it’s certainly got a long history of disproportionately racially charged usage.  [cont’d]

Comment: My best guess after this reading-around is that in recent years, it’s probably been used innocently by many, but with racial overtones in a few places/subcultures (quite possibly as a dog-whistle); and after a few high-profile political cases brought this to wider attention during the Obama campaign, a lot more people are now worried about it.  So… I’m not sure now how much I stand by the advice of “use with care”.  Hmm.

Comment: @PLL ~ The usecase of “uppity n****r” being as offensive as it is, uppity is just being a modifier on the already present racism. By itself uppity isn't normally termed a bad word, anywhere that I've heard. However, likell words, it can be used in a derogatory fashion, and when applied to another individual in such a derogatory fashion, that may imply racism. I would go with "used in context it's appropriate and highly acceptable".

Comment: @drachenstern: mostly agreed, but I think there’s a little more than that going on here.  If a word gets used disproportionately often in eg a racist context, then it starts carrying those connotations in other contexts as well.  An analogous case that’s more current and has progressed further: *flaming* had no overtones of sexuality until recently — the relevant senses in the OED include *extravagant*, *colourful*, *flamboyant*.  But it has become strongly enough linked to the phrases “flaming homosexual”, “flaming queer” etc. that now *flaming* alone can mean *gay* (cf. Urban Dictionary).

Comment: *Uppity* clearly hasn’t gone nearly this far, and is historically/geographically very patchy.  But I think the people who find it racist do so for reasons analogous to what’s happened with *flaming*.

Comment: @PLL ~ That's an excellent set of points. I hope it hasn't and won't go as far as _flaming_ has but I do see your point readily.

Answer (score 1):

**Intellectual snob** is a good noun for it.  Unfortunately the obvious adjectival version, *intellectually snobbish*, isn’t such a standard idiom, so doesn’t (to my ear) work quite as well.

If you’re in Britain or Australia, then **poncy** (adj.) or **ponce** (noun) will also do you well here.  I don’t think those are used much though (or even widely-known?) in the states; not sure about other countries.

Comment: OED lists only two meanings for *ponce* n. *derogatory slang* (chiefly *British):* "1. A man who lives on money earned by another person (esp. a woman); a kept man. Also: a person (usually a man) who lives off a prostitute's earnings; a pimp. /  2. *depreciative*. An effeminate or affected man or boy; (also) a homosexual man."

Answer (score 1):

Does that e-mail make me appear too meritocratic?

Answer (score 0):

I would call such a person a "diploma snob" ... but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

I like Al's `Pretentious` and `Pompous` offerings, but I'd also add `Conceited` as one on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but how about [vainglorious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vainglorious) (n. [vainglory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vainglory))?