# What is a negative word to describe people that love showing off their knowledge?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Similar to this question: [One's brilliant vocabulary and a tendency to show it off](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97268/ones-brilliant-vocabulary-and-a-tendency-to-show-it-off) and
[What's the word for "overly proud of your education"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10361/whats-the-word-for-overly-proud-of-your-education)

But the word I'm looking for is not limited to vocabulary.  These people often drop words and also random fact tidbits even when it's:

- A) obvious to everyone in the room
- B) it's obvious that he/she just wants to show off the fact that they know it
- **C) not always founded on knowledge or fact**

Also, I'm looking for a word that has a negative connotation.

Comment: There is a legion of words that could be used, which suggests that this question is far too broad.

Comment: If you are willing to use scatology, there is always *bullshitter*.

Comment: Why are you talking about me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A "Clavin" is dated but still funny.  [Cliff Clavin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_Clavin) was one of the main characters on one of the most popular sitcoms of all time in the US - Cheers.  He is the EXACT person that you describe in the most extreme way.

Terms I would use to describe Clavin would be:

1. Windbag
2. Bigmouth
3. Blowhard

**Clavin Quote #1:**

> Well ya see, Norm, it's like this. A herd of buffalo can only move as
>   fast as the slowest buffalo. And when the herd is hunted, it is the
>   slowest and weakest ones at the back that are killed first. This
>   natural selection is good for the herd as a whole, because the general
>   speed and health of the whole group keeps improving by the regular
>   killing of the weakest members. In much the same way, the human brain
>   can only operate as fast as the slowest brain cells. Excessive intake
>   of alcohol, as we know, kills brain cells. But naturally, it attacks
>   the slowest and weakest brain cells first. In this way, regular
>   consumption of beer eliminates the weaker brain cells, making the
>   brain a faster and more efficient machine. That's why you always feel
>   smarter after a few beers.

**Clavin Quote #2:**

> CLIFF CLAVIN -  You know Rebecca, I don't know why you're so concerned
>   about your figure. You know, back in the Renaissance times, full
>   figured women were revered.
>
> NORM PETERSON- Get out.
>
> CLIFF CLAVIN - It's true. Yeah, yeah, artists would only paint big,
>   voluptuous women. In fact, that's how they got rid of a lot of their
>   old paint.

**Clavin Quote #3**

> You know, there's a lot of misunderstanding about rats. The rodendus
>   vermikitis as they're called in Latin. It turns out our long tailed
>   friend wasn't after all responsible for the dreaded bubonic plague as
>   alleged through history. Yes, sir. It was caused by an animal called
>   the bubon. That's right, and the threat by the way is still with us.
>   So if anyone does see a bubon, contact your local authorities.

**Clavin Quote #4**

> Norm, it's a little known fact that the word Florida comes from the
>   language of the Okie Canokie Indians and it means, literally, place
>   where the old people come to sweat.

**Clavin Quote #5**

> You see Sammy, topless waitresses, scientific fact, they can deliver
>   drinks faster than their clothed counterparts.

Comment: A good answer, but one risks being seen as a "Claven" oneself by using the term.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh - He would give you 10 historical reasons why it would be OK to use his name here!

Comment: @RyeBread Love this answer, if only all people like this were just as humorous....haha

Comment: @ishikun - They are almost always that funny.  You are looking at them with the wrong attitude.

Comment: @RyeBread Maybe I need to try harder, or look for a different word haha

Comment: @ishikun - I have a Clavin at my work.  Little annoying sometimes but more laughs than anything.

Answer (score 7):

A smart alec is somebody who always knows the right answer and says clever things to such an extent that other people find it annoying.

Ex:

All right, smart alec, you tell us the answer.

Material from "Advanced Vocabulary and Grammar, 2002"

Comment: The Accepted answer is funny, but this answer actually answers the question.

Answer (score 6):

Know-it-all is a good noun that in my opinion is somewhat slangy: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/know-it-all. For me, this has the connotation of not always being correct.

Show-off is another noun that comes to mind: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/show-off

Answer (score 6):

The word to use is ***Pedant***.

The interesting part is that it has two pronunciations:

1. /'pɛdənt/ (pedd-unt)
2. /'pidənt/ (peed-unt)

So, whichever pronunciation you use in accusing someone,
if they truly **are** a pedant, they will correct your pronunciation.

Comment: I like this rendition, but I feel that a pedant speaks out of knowledge and logic.  I'm looking for something more along the lines of (excuse my language) people that just spew c***.

Comment: A pedant speaks from authority and superiority. In a teacher, this is appropriate; the word has always referred to instructing. In anyone else, it is normally considered arrogant to assume to instruct another person, unless requested.

Comment: This would answer the question perfectly, if it weren't for Condition C, namely that the person is putting out false data.  A Pedant is almost always correct in their pedantry, although not all pedants are aware of their own pedantry.  Some of them don't even notice that they are a pedant.  I would consider myself a pedant, if I were correct more often that I often am.  Unfortunately, I myself trend towards being a Clavin.  At least that is what my dear wife believes.

Comment: Pedants are no more correct than anyone else. They are simply more certain and confident. A good example would be the pedants who peeve so much about "violations" of "grammar rules" when in fact they don't know Bahnhof about grammar rules.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind being slangy, you might call such a person a *[smart-arse](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/smart-arse)*:-

> someone who is always trying to seem more clever than other people in
>   a way that is annoying: I don't want some smart-arse from the city
>   telling me how to manage my farm.

(American *smart-ass*; in either case don't expect them to like it.)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this as well before but I also want to add in the nuance of being stupid while simultaneously being a smart-ass.

Answer (score 1):

You can always call them a [pompous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pompous) [windbag](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/windbag).