# Word For Horribly Complicated For No Reason?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, american-english, philosophy

I've noticed that some people really love to overcomplicate things to seem intellectually superior. For instance, say I somehow dropped a pile of clothes on the ground. They'd then ask me: "When would I stop being a pile? If I keep taking away one article at a time, when would it no longer be a heap?" I'm asking if there's there a word for this needlessly philosophical behavior? Thanks!

Comment: "When would **I** stop being a pile" = "When would **it** [the pile] stop being a pile"?

Comment: Maybe you’re looking for ***pretentious*** but I’d call it *interesting critical thinking* that helps you understand these terms (pile and heap) more clearly.

Comment: The example you give is a little odd. Is there a reason you've used both 'heap' and 'pile'?

Comment: Related: [What is a negative word to describe people that love showing off their knowledge?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126570/what-is-a-negative-word-to-describe-people-that-love-showing-off-their-knowledge).

Comment: You could say such people are ***overanalytical*** (often shortened to just ***anal**!* :)

Answer (score 4):

The "when-is-a-pile-not-a-pile" question is the famous [Paradox of Sorites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox) (*sorites* being the Greek word for "pile").

Bringing up the paradox (or whatever other obscure issue) on any excuse might be "overintellectualizing" or just "snooty".

Comment: When less than 472.9634 grains are left. Or is that fewer?

Answer (score 2):

*single word:*

**philosophize**

[dicitionary.com definition:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/philosophize)

> to speculate or theorize, usually in a superficial or imprecise manner.

**pedantic**

[dictionary.com definition:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pedantic)

> 1.
>   ostentatious in one's learning.
>   2.
>   overly concerned with minute details or formalisms, especially in teaching.

**hairsplitting**

[dictionary.com definition:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hairsplitting)

> 2. characterized by [the making of unnecessarily fine distinctions].

**nitpicking**

[dictionary.com definition:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nit-picking)

> 1. to be excessively concerned with or critical of inconsequential details.

**overthink**

[dictionary.com definition:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overthink)

> to spend more time thinking about something than is necessary or productive

---

*idioms:*

**make a song and dance about nothing**

[cambridge dictionary definition:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-a-song-and-dance-about-sth)

> UK informal: to make something seem more important than it really is so that everyone notices it:
>
> similar: [**much ado about nothing**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/much+ado+about+nothing)

**make a mountain out of a molehill**

[wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_a_mountain_out_of_a_molehill)

> an idiom referring to over-reactive, histrionic behaviour where a person makes too much of a minor issue

Comment: I think "make a mountain out of a molehill" is especially appropriate in the context of OP's example. It does raise the question, though, of when *exactly* a molehill becomes a mountain.

Comment: @No More Secrets ~ good point, I didn't think of that secondary double entendre

Comment: Pedantic is the word I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for [**pretentious**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20pretentious):

> attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent,
>   culture, etc., than is actually possessed.
>
> *"a pretentious literary device"*
>
> **synonyms:** affected, ostentatious, showy; overambitious, pompous, artificial, inflated, overblown, high-sounding, flowery, grandiose,
>   elaborate, extravagant, flamboyant, ornate, grandiloquent,
>   magniloquent, sophomoric;
>
> **informal:** flashy, highfalutin, fancy-pants, la-di-da, pseudo
>
> *"Clytemnestra is a pretentious name for a dog"*

You might also consider [**obfuscate**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+obfuscate):

> render obscure, unclear, or unintelligible.
>
> *"the spelling changes will deform some familiar words and obfuscate their etymological origins"*
>
> **synonyms:** obscure, confuse, make unclear, blur, muddle, complicate, overcomplicate, muddy, cloud, befog
>
> *"mere rationalizations to obfuscate rather than clarify the real issue"*
>
> bewilder (someone).
>
> *"it is more likely to obfuscate people than enlighten them"*
>
> **synonyms:** bewilder, mystify, puzzle, perplex, confuse, baffle, confound, bemuse, befuddle, nonplus; informalflummox
>
> *"her work became more and more obfuscated by mathematics and jargon"*

Comment: +1 for *pretentious* -1 for *obfuscate*